# Why do white lines appear in my canvas when rendered on my iPad (Safari and Chrome)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ipad, html5-canvas, mobile-safari

I'm updating a canvas one row at a time using JS.  On my laptop, the canvas renders as expected.  On my iPad, white horizontal lines appear in the canvas at different rows every time I refresh.

[image]

If I zoom in or out on my iPad, the lines go away.  Any thoughts on why this is happening and how I can work around it?  I've tried forcing a repaint of the browser window via several methods mentioned on SO.  It didn't change anything.

Here is the code:  http://jsfiddle.net/RFf5r/

```
function paintRow(y)
{

    if(y == 100)
        return;

    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var imageData = ctx.createImageData(100, 1);

    var i = 0;
    for(x = 0; x<100; x++)
    {
        imageData.data[i] = x / 100 * 255;
        imageData.data[i+1] = 0;
        imageData.data[i+2] = 0;
        imageData.data[i+3] = 255;
        i+=4
    }

    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, y);


    setTimeout(function() { paintRow(y+1); }, 10);
}


paintRow(0);
```

Comment: That's maybe caused by its device pixel ratio. Since it has a retina display everything is enlarged by a factor of 2. Use `webkitGetImageDataHD` and `webkitPutImageDataHD()` instead: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/audiovideo/conceptual/html-canvas-guide/PixelManipulation/PixelManipulation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010542-CH16-SW4

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Tried as you suggested.  http://jsfiddle.net/7wsZP/ Now no pixels render inside the canvas (except border).  My ipad is a retina though.  Strange.

Comment: why not draw a plain line ? it's way faster on any device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a workaround that appears to work:

```
c.style.zoom = c.style.zoom == "100%" ? "100.0001%" : "100%";
```

after each update.